# how to achieve the sidebar look in the picture with html and css

Tags: html, css

So my idea is to have a map of a country and every pool of water to have a marker on it with its name, and when the marker is clicked I want a scrollable sidebar to appear that has all the fish species contained in that body of water. there should be a picture of the fish and a name and users should be able to click the picture to get more info. For better understanding, I drew a representation of what I want with paint.[image]

I only need help for the sidebar any ideas on what technology or style to use are appreciated

Comment: nothing i had no idea how to acomplish it

Answer (score -1):

If you are not familiar with flex-box (display: flex;), I'd suggest on hitting that first. Also, take a look at overflow: scroll; for your scroll effect.